# Merging two Mapfile that has same keys

Tags: hadoop

I have a use case wherein I generate a MapFile with key/value pairs in it. 
The contents are below

key1     [red, green, blue]

In some other occassion,I want to update the 'value' with more entries in it. I wanted to achieve this by generating a second map file that has same key with new entries

key1     [purple, yellow]

What I need is somehow I should be able to have a mapFile as follows

key1      [red, green, blue, purple, yellow]

Merging mapFiles will do this? Or, do we have any workaround for this?

regards
RAB

Answer (score 0):

```
 You can achieve this by following below steps :

   1) create two different mappers by creating two different classes 
   2) keep the same key in both mapper classes 
   3) In driver class make use of  MultiFileInputFormat .


All the values which belong to same key will automatically come to reducer then you can do what ever you want to do with value .
```

Comment: THanks for those responses. Yes, i will try MUltipleInputs method. Also, this can be done through Hadoop's sort utility? I use this to merge two map files but they both will have different keys. Have anyone tried this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it using **MultipleInputs**.

You can reuse the same map class as both the files are of same format. 
And in Reducer Join the values.

```
public class MultipleFiles
{
    public static class Map1 extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,Text>
    {
        public void map(LongWritable k, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {
            String line=value.toString();
            String[] words=line.split(" ");
            String val1=words[0];
            String val2=words[1];
            context.write(new Text(val1), new Text(val2));
        }
    }
    public static class Red extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text>
    {
        static String merge = "";

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
                throws IOException , InterruptedException
                {
            int i =0;
            for(Text value:values)
            {
                if(i == 0){
                    merge = value.toString()+",";
                }
                else{
                    merge += value.toString();
                }

                i++;
            }
            context.write(key, new Text(merge));

                }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Configuration c=new Configuration();
        String[] files=new GenericOptionsParser(c,args).getRemainingArgs();
        Path p1=new Path(files[0]);
        Path p2=new Path(files[1]);
        Path p3=new Path(files[2]);
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(c);
        if(fs.exists(p3)){
            fs.delete(p3, true);
        }
        Job j = new Job(c,"multiple");
        j.setJarByClass(MultipleFiles.class);
        j.setReducerClass(Red.class);
        j.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        j.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        MultipleInputs.addInputPath(j, p1, TextInputFormat.class, Map1.class);
        MultipleInputs.addInputPath(j,p2, TextInputFormat.class, Map1.class);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(j, p3);
        System.exit(j.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0:1);

    }

}
```

Comment: THanks for those responses. Yes, i will try MUltipleInputs method. Also, this can be done through Hadoop's sort utility? I use this to merge two map files but they both will have different keys. Have anyone tried this?